# How to use the Navigation Controller as a Navigation for my UIWebView [Xcode]?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am working on an update for my iOS App.
At the moment you can go back with a static back-button (created and linked in my storyboard), but I want a redirection over a navigation controller to a new WebView.
This is the code at the moment:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:url animated:YES];

    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

How can I do that ? 
Thank you very much in advance!!

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly this code doesn't make sense (e.g. `url` is not a `UIViewController` that is required by `pushViewController`, etc.), but we can make intelligent guesses about what you were trying to do. I'm guessing that you're saying that you want to make the back button act like the back button on a web browser, but you want the standard navigation controller to take care of that for you. The implication of that is that you're also suggesting that every time you click on a link on the page, you want to push to another view controller to show that next web page (so that the back button can take you back to the previous view controller with the previous web page).

If that's what you're asking, that's probably not a good idea. It would mean that every time you click on a link in the web browser, you'd need to have your `UIWebViewDelegate` method, `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, intercept that request, not have the current `UIWebView` satisfy that request, but rather push to another view controller with a UIWebView firing up that page. Sadly, that's a lot of work and incredibly wasteful of memory resources. It also wouldn't work on a lot of web pages. Bottom line, wouldn't be a great idea.

It's much easier to just add the button to your view controller hosting the `UIWebView`, and then let `UIWebView` do all it's magic. You can then add all the other buttons that users have grown to expect on iOS web browsers (not only back button but forward button, maybe a home button, maybe an "actions" button that lets you open the page in safari, share on fb, etc. Whatever you want. But users expect more than just a "back" button.

---

**Update:**

If you really want to push to another view controller when a user clicks on a link, you could intercept `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` as I mentioned earlier. The following code sample assumes, though:

- You've defined the view controller to be the delegate for the web view; and
- You have defined an `BOOL` instance variable, `loadFinished`.

Anyway, you probably want these three [`UIWebViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (!initialLoadFinished)
    {
        // if we're still loading this web view for the first time, then let's let
        // it do it's job

        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise, let's intercept the webview from going to the next
        // html link that the user tapped on, and create the new view controller.

        // I'm making the next controller by instantiating a scene from the
        // storyboard. Because you may be using NIBs or because you have different
        // class names and storyboard ids, you will have to change the following
        // line.

        ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webview"];

        // I don't know how you're passing the URL to your view controller. I'm
        // just setting a (NSString*)urlString property.

        controller.urlString = request.URL.absoluteString;

        // push to that next controller

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

        // and stop this web view from navigating to the next page

        return NO;
    }
}

// UIWebView calls this when the page load is done

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    initialLoadFinished = YES;
}

// UIWebView calls this if the page load failed. Note, though, that
// NSURLErrorCancelled is a well error that some web servers erroneously
// generate

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error.code != NSURLErrorCancelled)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Web Loading Error"
                                                        message:nil // error.localizedDescription
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        initialLoadFinished = YES;
    }
}
```

Personally, I'd probably stick with the standard `UIWebView`, but if you want to jump to navigation controllers, this will do it. By the way, the above hack might not handle redirects well, so make sure you get the URLs right.

Comment: Hey Rob! Thank you for your fast RE. You're right, but the page contains only two levels. So this is not the problem. Could you (or anyone other) show me such a code? It is very important. It shall act as a native app. The native content is on the device. The online informations will load from the web (in a webview).

Comment: @MDev I still don't get why you want to do it this way, but the updated answer shows you the sort of code that you could use to intercept the user's clicks on links, and push to another copy of the view controller with the `UIWebView`.